# Ubuntu 22.04 App Overview Screen Refresh glitching

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just updated my OS to 22.04 Ubuntu and ever since the reboot, the app overview screen has been glitching. It has been writing new visuals over the previous ones without erasing the previous images. I have tried disabling extensions, updating the graphics, and autoremoving packages.

One of the things I can think of is that when the OS was being updated, it quit midway through the installation. There are 6 or so stages. It reached the end of "Installation" stage but the program exited before reaching "Cleaning" and "Reboot" stages.

I will attach an image of the App overview screen. The screenshot I took shows the foreground render properly (i.e. the results of the search are showed properly, without overwrite), but the background looks like a png image background without checkered bg.

I can't think of anything else to try. Any help is greatly appreciated. Have a terrific day!

[image]